# The maximum possible deflection of the 2 kg particle is?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

A particle of mass $2 \text{ kg}$ moving with a speed of $6 \text{ m/s}$ collides elastically with another particle of mass $4 \text{ kg}$ traveling in same direction with a speed of $2 \text{ m/s}$.  The maximum possible deflection of the $2 \text{ kg}$ particle is?

The options are

(a) $36^\circ$,

(b) $45^\circ$,

(c) $53^\circ$,

(d) $60^\circ$

(all in degrees).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conservation of energy (is conserved by the collision being elastically) and conservation of momentum. Define $m_1=2$, $m_2=4$, $v_1=6$, $v_2=2$.

The total energy is 
$$\frac 1 2 m_1 v_1^2+\frac 1 2 m_2 v_2^2=44.$$
The total momentum in the direction of collision is
$$m_1 v_1+m_2 v_2=20.$$
Now let $u_1$ and $u_2$ be their final velocities and $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ the angles with respect to the direction of collision, then we have by conservation of energy,
$$44=\frac 1 2 m_1 u_1^2+\frac 1 2 m_2 u_2^2,$$
and by conservation of momentum along the direction of collision is
$$m_1 u_1 \cos \alpha_1+m_2 u_2 \cos \alpha_2=20$$
and along the perpendicular direcition, 
$$m_1 u_1 \sin \alpha_1+m_2 u_2 \sin \alpha_2=0,$$
since their is no momentum in this direction before the collision. Can you maximize for $\alpha_1$ now under these constraints?

Hint: the maximum is attained at $u_2=2 \sqrt{5}$, so we have $\alpha_1\approx-53.13010234$, so (c) is correct.